# Meta viewport width on all devices

Tags: html, mobile, meta-tags

I have a website with a full width of `420px`, and I want this to be visible on mobile devices by having it load up in a zoomed out state.

So for this I have used:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=420">
```

This displays exactly how I want it to on my Samsung Galaxy S4 **Phone** in portrait mode, but when I turn it into landscape it scales the whole website up to the full width of the screen, which looks way too big.

I have also tested it on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 **Tablet**, and it scales it up on there too (Portrait & Landscape), which obviously looks even worse.

How do I get it to scale down on my phone in portrait mode (like it is now), but display a true width on other larger devices?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this by adding `initial-scale=1` to the Meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=420, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this viewport will work for all device

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale-1">`